# How to detect if user burned tokens

Tags: erc-20, nodejs, ethereumjs, burn

Looking through the code of ERC20 tokens they have the ability to burn and mint new tokens.  I want to write a nodejs program that monitors if a user burns a token and then sends them a new one if they do.  I already know how to send tokens but I can't seem to figure out how to check if they have burnt the old token.  Ideally, I would also be able to check how many confirms burn has.

Comment: What do you mean by "burned"? Sent to the [zero address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000)? Called the "burn" method on the ERC-20 contact?

Comment: For the latter, you might want to use an indexing service like [The Graph](https://thegraph.com).

Comment: Called burn method.  Will look in to the graph but what I am hoping is to be able to use web3 to check myself.

Comment: usually burn functions emit an event "Transfer(account, address(0), amount);" but not all implementations do this. I don't know your use case (this is only an abstract answer without a warranty)

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse what do you mean by "web3"? The web3.js library? Indexing events with that library is not easy. I highly recommend you look into The Graph.

Comment: thanks looks like some experimentation is in order.  I didn't write the contract.

Answer (score 1):

If by burn you mean call the burn method, you can add an event emit in your burn function that you listen in a script and send the amount burn to the "burner" every time you notice that someone burnt some tokens.

If you mean tokens sent to 0x0 address, you can monitor all the tokens transfers in your script and send the amount burn every time you see someone sending your token to 0x0.